# Django Form Select Field from linked ModelChoiceFields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am building a form for a store that will allow clients to choose a price from a number of choices. The current Django template looks like so and works very well.

```
<select>
    <option>{{ p.equipment_list.season_price.currency }} {{ p.equipment_list.season_price.daily }} per day.</option>
    <option>{{ p.equipment_list.season_price.currency }} {{ p.equipment_list.season_price.weekly }} per week.</option>
    <option>{{ p.equipment_list.season_price.currency }} {{ p.equipment_list.season_price.monthly }} per month.</option>
</select>
```

I have a product 'p' that is part of a group called Equipment List. This list has different pricing (season_price) depending on the time of year or through an sale offer. This allows maximum customizability and separation of tasks. Here are the models:

```
class SeasonPrice(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Season Price'), max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
    daily = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    weekly = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    monthly = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
…

class EquipmentList(models.Model):
   ...
    name = models.CharField(_('Equipment List'), max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    season_price = models.ForeignKey(SeasonPrice)
    ….

class Product(ImageModel):
     ...
    equipment_list = models.ForeignKey(EquipmentList, related_name='Equipment')

    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

   …
    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return ('product_detail', (), {'product_slug': self.slug})

   ….
```

The form looks something like this:

```
class ProductAddToCartForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    product_slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    price = forms.ModelChoiceField(EquipmentList)
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'2', 'value':'1', 'class':'quantity'}), 
                                  error_messages={'invalid':'Please enter a valid quantity.'}, 
                                  min_value=1)
   ...
```

And the View:

```
def show_product(request, product_slug, template_name="shop/product_detail.html"):

    p = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product_slug)
    page_title = p.name


    # need to evaluate the HTTP method
    if request.method == 'POST':

        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = ProductAddToCartForm(request, postdata)

        if form.is_valid():
            cart.add_to_cart(request)
            url = urlresolvers.reverse('show_cart')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:

        form = ProductAddToCartForm(request=request, label_suffix=':')

    form.fields['product_slug'].widget.attrs['value'] = product_slug
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    return render_to_response("shop/product_detail.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

All the examples that I have seen of ModelChoiceField are one ForeignKey deep. From the above, I want to be able to chain-link 2 to 3 ForeignKeys and output a numeral string to be multiplied with the quantity the shopper wants and then place into a shopping cart.

Thanks

Comment: Can you pls explain a bit more in detail what you mean with "chain-link 2 to 3 ForeignKeys and output a numeral string to be multiplied with the quantity the shopper..." - does this mean you want to populate some other field with the choices? or is this about the labels of the ModelChoiceField?

Comment: Hi Lazerscience, from the above template tag <option>{{ p.equipment_list.season_price.currency }}, the equipment_list attribue is a ForeignKey of the product model, the season_price is a ForeignKey in the equipment_list model and currency is a ForeignKey of the season_price model. The question is whether I can reproduce this in a form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `ModelChoiceField` is appropriate for the original `<select>` you show.  You are choosing a currency/decimal combination, not a model instance.  Probably, you want to build an ad-hoc `ChoiceField`.

```
myform.fields['price'].choices = (
    ('1::3.50', "EUR 3.50 per day"),
    # ...
)
```

where `1::3.50` can be split() in clean/save to give the currency id and the amount string. Something like that.